# Get password-protected PFX thumbprint if I cannot install the PFX?

Tags: azure, certificate, system-administration, pfx

I have the root cert for my organization's development environment (self-signed) and I've generated a whole bunch of client certs for VPN access. However I thought it would be best to not keep the certificate install password anywhere I could access it later (more secure, I reasoned), and I generated GUIDs for the purposes of installation before securely transmitting their cert password.

I kept the certs thinking I could access the thumbprint for future revocation if I had it. However when I needed to revoke a certificate recently I realized the only way I know how to access the thumbprint is to install the cert locally and run powershell to extract the thumbprint using

```
(Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My | Out-GridView -Title "Select VPN certificate to revoke" -PassThru).Thumbprint
```

I have a few of the original emails saved which contain the GUID passwords, but a majority of them are gone and they won't expire for over a year.

I assume my only option is to revoke the dev root cert and reissue the client certs, but I wanted to check here to see if there was any other way. I know the thumbprints are encrypted using SHA-1.

Is there any other way to acquire this thumbprint with the information I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this and needs an answer, I very luckily had not deleted most of the original emails that contained the cert passwords and was able to extract the thumbprints and save those, which I then deleted (don't want to have passwords source controlled or anything).

However my backup plan was to invalidate the dev cert and reissue all, which is made pretty easy with proper process.